# Bootstrap <li> badge element in the right place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, badge

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUVkZ/).

And for you guys understand, the split of the jsfiddle must be in a certain position. So, here's a printscreen.

[image]

The code in the jsfiddle works perfectly for mobile or bigger dimensions but I need it to that certain width. As you can see in the image, it's explained what I want. I want the badges to be always at right of the text no matter the propotions of the text.

I thought about the possibility of the `<div>` inside the `<li>`, but for what I've tried I got no success.

Comment: Looks like you added wrong Jsfiddle link

Comment: [I see it works](http://jsfiddle.net/ZUVkZ/1/).